# Observe_field in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I had a dropdown. I need to add a textbox when the value changes in the dropdown. I had done this using "obseve_field" tag in rails 2.3.5. Now I am moving into rails 3. So how I write it in rails 3.

Answer (score 16):

If you want to use the legacy Prototype helpers (like `observe_field`) in Rails 3, check out the [GitHub repository for `prototype_legacy_helper`](http://github.com/rails/prototype_legacy_helper).

Otherwise, you can write this JavaScript yourself using the new UJS. See these two blocks of code for the old `observe_field` method:

- http://github.com/rails/prototype_legacy_helper/blob/c91b90/lib/prototype_helper.rb#L359-365
- http://github.com/rails/prototype_legacy_helper/blob/c91b90/lib/prototype_helper.rb#L415-429

and see Part 2 at http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-in-rails-3/ to see how to do this in jQuery.

Comment: what about rails 3.2? got Uncaught ReferenceError: Form is not defined error