# Dependent select boxes in rails with collect

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

i have three select list fill with collect, but from same "product" table:

```
    <p>
            <span>Categoria:</span><%= select :search, :search1, [["Seleccionar", "none"]] + Product.all(:group => "category", :order => "category").collect {|a| [a.category, a.category]} %>
          </p>
           <p>
           <span>Subcategoria:</span><%= select :search, :search2, [["Seleccionar", "none"]] + Product.all(:group => "subcategory", :order => "subcategory").collect {|b| [b.subcategory, b.subcategory]} %>
           </p>
            <p>
            <span>Subcubategoria:</span><%= select :search, :search3, [["Seleccionar", "none"]] + Product.all(:group => "subsubcategory", :order => "subsubcategory").collect {|c| [c.subsubcategory, c.subsubcategory]} %>
</p>
```

so i like dependent each other.

any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little bit confusing, but if you want some of the select boxes to update based on the selections in previous select boxes then look up [`observe_field`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/observe_field) (and the methods for [replicating its behaviour in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846089/observe-field-in-rails-3)) for some guidance.